# How do you access a class?

Tags: java

I have

```
public class TestApp { // TestApp.java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TestClass x = new TestClass(); // compiler error
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TestClass { // TestClass.java
    public TestClass() {
    }
}
```

TestClass was created by right clicking the project and clicking Add Class.

I'm using NetBeans

Comment: What does the error say? I don't see anything blatantly wrong.

Comment: What is the compiler error? You probably haven't imported TestClass.

Comment: Are you trying to **use** the class?

Comment: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class TestClass
  location: class TestApp

Comment: did you specify/import the right package?

Comment: Is TestClass in a package different from the one of TestApp? Please post the imports of TestApp.

Comment: once i put it in the src directory it worked. is that where its supposed to go? this is for a tiny personal project so its not a huge deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

classes are known by their name, their *full* name !

com.myapplication.mymodule.Myclass

you can use the short part provided you :

- use an import statement : import com.myapplication.mymodule.Myclass
- use the short name in a class with same package

from your sample, before using import, you can to use full name :

```
com.test.TestClass x = new com.test.TestClass(); // change "com.test" for the real package
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't declare a package for either class:

The reason it worked after you placed them in the same folder is that they both became part of the same package.

This is the default unnamed package. All source files without a package declaration, in the same source folder, belong to that folders default package. Also, they cannot be imported for use in other packages.

It's useful for small test apps, but you should strive to put all classes in a proper package.